# php / SQLite3 RAM usage: how is it affected by PRAGMA mmap_size?

Tags: php, sqlite, concurrency, mmap, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm working on a php / [SQLite3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) program to run on web servers. It happens to be a persistent object cache plugin for WordPress. The table is a very simple key/value/timestamp store (TEXT/BLOB/INT) with the key as PK and an index on timestamp. It works correctly, and now I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

Using SQLite's [PRAGMA mmap_size = 16_777_216](https://www.sqlite.org/mmap.html) operation, I'm directing SQLite to memory-map the SQLite database file in an attempt to speed things up in concurrent use.

Changing the memory mapped size, or zeroing it, doesn't affect the output of [memory_get_peak_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) (on Ubuntu Linux anyhow) at the end of each page request.

In low-concurrency testing I get mild speedups by memory mapping. The speedup is small enough that I wonder whether the memory mapping is worth it.

Is it possible for memory mapped SQLite to cause RAM exhaustion issues in a busy php / apache2 or php / nginx server? Is there any way to inspect or trace memory usage, so I can make a good decision about using this feature of SQLite?